# useSelector with useDispatch causing infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

so I am calling useDispatch inside useEffect with empty dependency (componentdidmount) and updating a state in redux store , I am also trying to access the same state in the same component using useSelector but it causes infinite loop, any idea why? thanks

my code is something similar to this:

```
export const PostsByTerm = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchPostsByTerm(payload));  
  }, [])

  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.postsByTerm);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="post_heading">Posts</h1>
      {posts ? posts.map((post) => <h1>{post.entityLable}</h1>) : <h1>no posts</h1>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

1. This is happening because due to the fact that you're using a part of the Redux state (i.e. the `posts` which you extract from Redux store using `useSelector`), your component will automatically re-render when the state changes.
2. However, each time you are mounting your component, you are also calling the `dispatch` method in your `useEffect` that changes the Redux store and causes your component to re-render.
3. Again, during the re-render, your `useEffect` runs the `dispatch` function that causes a Redux store update which in turn causes yet another re-render and this is how you've gotten caught up in an infinite loop of re-renders and Redux store updates
4. A solution to this might be to only run `dispatch` only when the `payload` changes by running the `useEffect` exclusively when `payload` changes and not when component mounts
5. You can use the following code for the same :

**useUpdateEffect** - custom react hook that will only run when dependencies change

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react"

export default function useUpdateEffect(callback, dependencies) {
  const firstRenderRef = useRef(true)

  // Since ref persists value between renders (and itself doesn't trigger a render when value is changed), we can simply just set ref to a failing condition on our 1st render so that component only is re-rendered when dependencies change and not also "onMount"
  useEffect(() => {
    if (firstRenderRef.current) {
      firstRenderRef.current = false
      return
    }
    return callback()
  }, dependencies)
}
```

Using the `useUpdateEffect` hook in our code :

```
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useUpdateEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchPostsByTerm(payload));  
  }, [payload])

  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.postsByTerm);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="post_heading">Posts</h1>
      {posts ? posts.map((post) => <h1>{post.entityLable}</h1>) : <h1>no posts</h1>}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: shouldn't a library like reselect handle passing back the same object references so that useSelector doesn't re-render the component regardless of how many times store gets updated from a dispatched action?

Answer (score -1):

just write dispatch in dependency array like this [dispatch]